# folder permissions

Tags: permissions, directory, users

I have a user `user1` that belongs to `group1` as primary group, but I need this user to have read/write access to a folder that belongs to `group2`.

I tried adding a secondary group to this user so it now belongs to `group1` as primary group and `group2` as secondary group but I still don't have access to the folder.

I used this command to add the primary group `usermod -g group1 user1` and this one to add the secondary group `usermod -a -G group2 user1`

This are my folders permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 owner  group1     4096 jun  5 10:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x  6 owner  owner      4096 jun  5 10:03 ../
drwxrwx--- 14 owner  group1     4096 jun  5 11:12 folder1
drwxrwx---  5 owner  group1     4096 may 24 11:32 folder2
drwxrwx--- 13 owner  group2     4096 jun  5 10:29 folder3
drwxrwx---  3 owner  group2     4096 jun  5 10:26 folder4
drwxrwx---  8 owner  group2     4096 jun  5 10:25 folder5
drwxrwx---  6 owner  group1     4096 jun  2 09:19 folder6
```

Can you help me solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to KamilMaciorowski for the answer I need to modify the smb.conf file and add the new group in order to be able to have access.

I modify it this way:

```
[PEI]
    browsable = yes
    path = smb/dir
    guest ok = no
    guest only = no
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    write list = @group1, @group2
    read list =
    valid users = @group1, @group2
    read only = no
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (but it's confusing) I think you've to approach this the other way around. If I understand you correctly you tried to add a group to an user.
What would work is adding the user to a group.
If you want user1 to have access to folders/ files of group 2, do:

`sudo adduser user1 group2`

Comment: Wow, I really didn't make my self clear, i'm sorry what i'm trying to do is give permissions to one single user with two different groups.